# Concerning appropriate questions: Where is "mainstream physics" emphasized?

Tags: discussion, scope, non-mainstream-physics

In a comment to my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/is-it-true-that-gravitational-lensing-only-occurs-for-objects-made-of-plasma/119596#119596) I was asked:

> *and can you provide source for that this forum is only for mainstream physics, what is mainstream?*

I thought that this was written in the help page, but cannot find it. It is sort of implied in the list of appropriate questions but there is no discouragement of crackpot theory type discussions in the red x list.

Is it my impression that somewhere the "mainstream physics" was emphasized? Anyway why isn't it?

Comment: The term _mainstream physics_ is e.g. mentioned in the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See the sentence "We deal with mainstream physics here" a bit down on that page, which in turn links to [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4538/2451) related meta question.

Comment: @Qmechanic no, it is implied, the word is not there

Comment: @Qmechanic I am looking with the firefox search on the links coming up at "help" and "mainstream" or "main stream" do not come up. The help in the main physics page . I do not get your link. I get http://physics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Qmechanic OK, it is at second level and I did not find it by searching with the find in edit. I do think it could be made more easy to find for first users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new user joins, they are shown the [tour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) page. I added a link and explicitly mentioned non-mainstream there. That should help.

Comment: I also updated the wording in the help center to match

Comment: fine, thanks a lot, because I wanted to point the questioner to a link and I had to search for it. It is now easy

Answer (score 4):

Look at the second set of bullet point in the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help).

A partial quote reads:

> Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: [...]
>
> - **Pitches for your own personal theories or work**
>     We deal with mainstream physics here. Anything that couldn't be 
>     published in a reputable journal is not appropriate on this site.
> - **Questions about fictional physics**
>     "Could a warp drive get you out of a black hole?"
>     Questions about physics of fictional worlds which are not sufficiently grounded in real physics are off topic here, but they may be on topic at Science Fiction & Fantasy.

The bit about *"[a]nything that could not be published in a reputable journal"* is the key, and I suppose that this is the standard to use in judging the extent of "mainstream"-ness required.

Also, remember that some theories that are widely considered to be unlikely are none-the-less publishable. People did MOND for decades despite a near consensus that the work was doomed.

Comment: Yes,but it is titled "piches for your onw personal theories or work.  Not about discussing other people's. I found this wiki answer http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4538/ which covers clearly the matter, but it is not easily found to answer the question by a new user.

Comment: Let's bring this up in the chat session, and we can clarify the wording in the help center.

Comment: @annav It's been pointed out that the meta question you linked to is directly linked from the help center; I'm not sure how it could be made easier to find.

Comment: Worth noting that this has been edited since you posted your answer